# How to display values ​with two decimal places keeping the number 0

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

In Google Big Query How to display values ​​with two decimal places keeping the number 0?

Example: I have the following query that rounds values ​​to two decimal places, but its return with the value, for example, of 0.80 is displayed as 0.8. I would like it to be displayed as 0.80, how can I do this in the big query?

```
  SELECT 
        a.companyname,
        a.ticker,
        a.price,
        round(a.p_l,2) as p_l,
        round(a.p_vp,2) as p_vp,
        round(a.dy,2) as dy
  FROM `acoes-378306.acoes.data_acoes` as a
  where a.lpa > 0 
  and a.vpa > 0 
  and price > 0 
  and a.ticker = 'MRFG3'
```

[image]

Comment: cast it as string and format it, or cast it as decimal (9,2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *FORMAT()* function with *precision* instead like below

```sql
SELECT FORMAT('%.2f', 0.8), FORMAT('%.2f', 34.1);
```

**Query results**

[image]

**See also:**

- https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#format_string

Comment: It was simpler than the solution I put below, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
        a.companyname,
        a.ticker,
        a.price,
        CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2), a.p_l) as p_l,
        CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),a.p_vp) as p_vp,
        CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2), a.dy,2) as dy
  FROM `acoes-378306.acoes.data_acoes` as a
  where a.lpa > 0 
  and a.vpa > 0 
  and price > 0 
  and a.ticker = 'MRFG3'
```

Comment: In the big query, it is informed that there is no CONVERT function

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it as follows:

```
    SELECT 
        a.companyname,
        a.ticker,
        a.price,
        case when a.p_l < 1 then rpad(cast(round(a.p_l,2) AS STRING), 4, '0') else rpad(cast(round(a.p_l,2) AS STRING), 5, '0') end as p_l,
        case when a.p_vp < 1 then rpad(cast(round(a.p_vp,2) AS STRING), 4, '0') else rpad(cast(round(a.p_vp,2) AS STRING), 5, '0') end as p_vp,
        case when a.dy < 1 then rpad(cast(round(a.dy,2) AS STRING), 4, '0') else rpad(cast(round(a.dy,2) AS STRING), 5, '0') end as dy
  FROM `acoes-378306.acoes.data_acoes` as a
  where a.lpa > 0 
  and a.vpa > 0 
  and price > 0 
  and a.ticker = 'MRFG3'
```

[image]